# Media Queries css working in safari but fails in chrome

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
@media only screen and(max-width: 1132px) {
#yc-contact{
    margin-left: 50px;
           }
}

 @media screen and(max-width: 1132px) {
#yc-contact{
    margin-left: 50px;
           }
}
```

The above code works in Safari but fails to work in Chrome. Tried both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Apply this code :

/* ----------- Non-Retina Screens ----------- */

```
  @media screen 
   and (max-device-width: 1132px) 
   and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) 
   { 
     #yc-contact{margin-left: 50px;}    
   }
```

/* ----------- Retina Screens ----------- */

```
  @media screen 
  and (max-device-width: 1132px) 
  and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (max-resolution: 192dpi) 
  {
   #yc-contact{margin-left: 50px;}
   }
```

Comment: where can i find these queries for all browsers

Comment: You can find the all other media quires for different different devices from this [link](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/)

Answer (score 2):

It seems a syntax error. Try to put a space after "and"

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1132px) {
#yc-contact{
    margin-left: 50px;
}

}
```

Comment: @Y07 — Adding the space fixed it when I tested it (it also removed the error reported by https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ )